# Node.js: The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token

Tags: javascript, node.js, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing a Flutter mobile app. From my Nodejs backend, I am trying to send FCM Notifications to the app. I downloaded the private key file from firebase console's project settings. Below is my Nodejs code.

```
const errorCodes = require('source/error-codes');
const PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');
const serviceAccount = require("service-account.json");
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

var {
    google
} = require('googleapis');
var MESSAGING_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging';
var SCOPES = [MESSAGING_SCOPE];

const prop = PropertiesReader('properties.properties');

exports.sendSingleNotification = async (event, context) => {

    const params = event.queryStringParameters;

    var PROJECT_ID = "xxxx-xxxx";
    var HOST = "fcm.googleapis.com";
    var PATH = "/v1/projects/" + PROJECT_ID + "/messages:send";


    try {

        let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var key = require("service-account.json");
            var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
                key.client_email,
                null,
                key.private_key,
                SCOPES,
                null
            );
            jwtClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                    return {
                        "error": "error 1"
                    };
                }
                resolve(tokens.access_token);
            });
        });

        let accessToken = await promise;

        // var options = {
        //     hostname: HOST,
        //     path: PATH,
        //     method: 'POST',
        //     headers: {
        //         'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
        //     }
        //     // … plus the body of your notification or data message
        // };

        var message = {
            "message": {
                "token": params.fcmtoken,
                "notification": {
                    "title": "Portugal vs. Denmark",
                    "body": "great match!"
                }
            }
        };

        const response = await fetch('https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/' + PROJECT_ID + '/messages:send', {
            method: 'post',
            body: JSON.stringify(message),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
            }
        });
        const data = await response.json();

        // var request = https.request(options, function(resp) {
        //     resp.setEncoding("utf8");
        //     resp.on("data", function(data) {
        //         console.log("Message sent to Firebase for delivery, response:");
        //         console.log(data);
        //     });
        // });
        // request.on("error", function(err) {
        //     console.log("Unable to send message to Firebase");
        //     console.log(err);
        // });
        // request.write(JSON.stringify(message));
        // request.end();



        return {
            "message": data
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return {
            "error 2": error
        }
    }


};
```

Below is the content in my `service-account.json` file

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "xxx-xxx",
  "private_key_id": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxx+xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxx\xxxxx\xxxx+xxxx/xxx+xxxx\xxxx/lw/jiWVj6R6ZXYFtq0SloyRSQQufiPROEtQVZ/kYoxrQs5BZ\nt+9McW3Jtq5SMnYQIMUV1WdXOG+8a8ru2szOZmzLLaQr5RCGLUgdmGE2OP+04aSp\nEMEu00DThQXYOLxUs5N2WOGfJ6Cpz9tfZR5fdBHbI0yJ/QEsFXKM5+gxsV23aFhj\neAqWu4Gxr+lKV1h4ccpLk4O4teWcrcjLZS/h+xxxxx/AETt8mff\nqy4PDZPsdYObjpPWM42VaaFv4wD2rjQigYN5SdglVhOjkihLAQM2+hhfO/gLA+Ub\nsD15Sp+xxxxx\xxxxx/xxxxx+mpPDpISVtN\ngFEBqWYHhQYpQIpdAmQ7HhBLh5Gquf7w9OzdEZnfCeZGNzfeJ9NQJyefzqD9Ejsp\xxxxx+Og6vSGIrr9jUhkImxtayRIfZSAhufXP/gexq\xxxxx+WVbeWjP8xt2Iule0hM3Qbtkppw9D\nxqxh+xxxxx\n2PJyY43L+iv/fLG5unhOBT4oYL6pFEt/DzSAaI+xxxxx\xxxx+xxxx/xxxx/xxxx\xxxxx/UJDCGr\xxxxx+Z5AoGBAJcLKoE0EaUVPN1BD7jg\xxxxx+hnMGS0qWUw2AsYxeJXTLa7zWpkd9i8X5Evd5QlNm8BWaOj\xxxx+xxxx\xxxx/EJagS1\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "firebase-adminsdk-fguv2@xxx-xxx.xxx.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/xxx/firebase-adminsdk-fguv2%40xxx-xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

In my Flutter app, below is how I get the FCM Token.

```
String? token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
```

When I run my Node.JS code, I always end up with the following error. I am passing the FCM Token generated by the above flutter code.

```
    {
        "message": {
            "error": {
                "code": 400,
                "message": "The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token",
                "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
                "details": [
                    {
                        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
                        "errorCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }

}
```

If it helps, below is the `accessToken` I get from the Node.js code. I am posting this because it looks weird to me anyways. The real code is converted into `xxx` here but notice the lot of dots (.) available in the authentication token!

```
xxx.c.xxx-G0WwTjZbMZQ1Bh0xxxxxxxxxxx_o5wl4U1A7cIJN3t87k10DqyEo4Wu1CJu_vFrva0-S9nkwxlVmG3AAjxfYIyVFsszcbrcF-xxxxxx........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
```

Why is this happening and How to fix this issue? FYI I tried the `firebase admin-sdk` for Nodejs and the result is same as this.

Comment: Do you get the access_token successfully

Comment: @nhCoder I have posted my access token in my question.

Comment: have you checked on this - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message?authuser=1? 
Maybe try without that `message` nested-object, hm? Also have you tried `onTokenRefresh` - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/client#access_the_registration_token?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the issue myself and wanted to share it for the benefit of others.

The important thing is that my code is correct, nothing wrong with it. However I was trying to execute this as a `get` function and I have passed the FCM Token as a parameter. This didnt work because the parameters contains a max length limit. As a result, my parameter got truncated when sending to the server.

All what I had to do is convert this call to a `post` and send the FCM Token in the `body`.